# Setting the backgroung of a Dialog box as transparent

Tags: android

I am working on an  android application that allows user to add an edit text dynamically. I have been able to add the edit text using an alert dialog. But I need to make the dialog box transparent .I need to be able to see the imageview in the background. Color.Transparent wont work because my background is an image

Comment: I'm confused..do you want set the background of the edittext as transparent or the dialog background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

or

```
mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/purpose_textfield"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@null"/>
```

Comment: Looks like the user was asking about Dialog's background!

Comment: yepp.. the title of the question was really misleading

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using alert Dialog Box, i prefer you to use Dialog box:

And use this code:

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);